# genetic algorithm crossover operation

Tags: genetic-algorithm, crossover

I am trying to implement a basic genetic algorithm in MATLAB. I have some questions regarding the cross-over operation. I was reading materials on it and I found that always two parents are selected for cross-over operation.

1. What happens if I happen to have an odd number of parents?
2. Suppose I have parent A, parent B & parent C  and I cross parent A with B and again parent B with C to produce offspring, even then I get 4 offspring. What is the criteria for rejecting one of them, as my population pool should remain the same always? Should I just reject the offspring with the lowest fitness value ?
3. Can an arithmetic operation between parents, like suppose OR or AND operation be deemed a good crossover operation? I found some sites listing them as crossover operations but I am not sure.
4. How can I do crossover between multiple parents ?

Answer (score 1):

"Crossover" isn't so much a well-defined operator as the generic idea of taking aspects of parents and using them to produce offspring similar to each parent in some ways. As such, there's no real right answer to the question of how one should do crossover.

In practice, you should do whatever makes sense for your problem domain and encoding. With things like two parent recombination of binary encoded individuals, there are some obvious choices -- things like n-point and uniform crossover, for instance. For real-valued encodings, there are things like SBX that aren't really sensible if viewed from a strict biological perspective. Rather, they are simply engineered to have some predetermined properties. Similarly, permutation encodings offer numerous well-known operators (Order crossover, Cycle crossover, Edge-assembly crossover, etc.) that, again, are the result of analysis of what features in parents make sense to make heritable for particular problem domains.

You're free to do the same thing. If you have three parents (with some discrete encoding like binary), you could do something like the following:

```
child = new chromosome(L)
for i=1 to L
    switch(rand(3))
        case 0:
            child[i] = parentA[i]
        case 1:
            child[i] = parentB[i]
        case 2:
            child[i] = parentC[i]
```

Whether that is a good operator or not will depend on several factors (problem domain, the interpretation of the encoding, etc.), but it's a perfectly legal way of producing offspring. You could also invent your own more complex method, e.g., taking a weighted average of each allele value over multiple parents, doing boolean operations like AND and OR, etc. You can also build a more "structured" operator if you like in which different parents have specific roles. The basic Differential Evolution algorithm selects three parents, a, b, and c, and computes an update like `a + F(b - c)` (with some function F) roughly corresponding to an offspring.

Answer (score 0):

Consider reading the following academic articles:

- DEB, Kalyanmoy et al. A fast and elitist multiobjective genetic algorithm: NSGA-II. IEEE transactions on evolutionary computation, v. 6, n. 2, p. 182-197, 2002.
- DEB, Kalyanmoy; AGRAWAL, Ram Bhushan. Simulated binary crossover for continuous search space. Complex systems, v. 9, n. 2, p. 115-148, 1995.

For SBX, method of crossing and mutate children mentioned by @deong, see answer [simulated-binary-crossover-sbx-crossover-operator-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457941/simulated-binary-crossover-sbx-crossover-operator-example/58829624#58829624)

Genetic algorithm does not have an arbitrary and definite form to be made. Many ways are proposed. But generally, what applies in all are the following steps:

1. Generate a random population by lot or any other method
2. Cross parents to raise children
3. Mutate
4. Evaluate the children and parents
5. Generate new population based only on children or children and parents (different approaches exist)
6. Return to item 2

NSGA-II, the DEB quoted above, is one of the most widely used and well-known genetic algorithms. See an image of the flow taken from the article:

[image]